# What HTTP code to use when redirecting to random page

Tags: seo, redirects

I have an URL `domain.com/random`, which will redirect to a random page.

What would be the correct HTTP code for this?

Plus, I'm inserting the link like this:

```
<a href="/random" rel="nofollow" title="Random profile">Show random profile</a>
```

Spiders won't follow that link. Do I need to care about what HTTP code I send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should send an HTTP code (apart from the usual 200). Spiders may or may not follow that link. If they do follow it they may decide to give it lesser weight, but still pay attention to it. The 301/302 redirects say "what used to be here is now somewhere else", but there was never anything at your random link in the first place. Even if there was, because you send them to a random place it's not true that whatever was there is somewhere else, because it's always somewhere different.

Comment: Yes, now that you say this, it makes more sense to just use 200.

Comment: `301` is definitely incorrect, though; it's considered a cache-able redirect, which is not what you want.  Arguably, `303` would be the best option given what you've described here, but `302` is a more common choice.